# Safari web inspector next match?

Tags: search, safari, find, web-inspector

I am searching my Javascript file for certain text.  I entered that text into the search box, and it helpfully tells me that there are four matches.  So far, so good.  But how can I go to the next/previous match?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hit Return and Shift-Return.